# Remote Validation in MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

I am trying to validate password by matching the previous password entered and I am successful to validate after login into my application but when I try to validate by forcing the user to change password before login, the remote validation is not working.

Below is my code:

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsPasswordValid", "Account", AdditionalFields = "UserName", ErrorMessage = "Password must differ from your Username and old 
Passwords")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
```

Remote Validation:

```
public JsonResult IsPasswordValid(string Username, string Password)
{
   responseClass response = service.IsDuplicatePassword(Username.ToLower(), Password);
   return Json((response != null && response.Status.Equals(1)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:(Rendering Below Scripts)

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", 
placeholder = "Please enter your Username" })
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</div></div>

<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)<br />
     @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter your New Password" })

<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</div></div>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the name attribute value of **UserName** and **Password** controls in the HTML? If possible post the HTML code

Comment: You can visit this link to refer. Hope to help, my friend. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Do the IsPasswordValid method gets hit? What is the business logic of **IsDuplicatePassword**?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I have added the code of IsDuplicatePassword above the html code, and is hitting after i login to my application but not before

Comment: Are you using any CustomAuthorize attribute?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I have used [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder I had not mentioned any attribute for validation method but after I mention [AllowAnonymous] its working, thanks a lot for your suggestions.